# Resolving mixed slashes when importing a module

Tags: windows, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to import a module from another directory that stems from the same parent.  I got the code to work in Python 2.7 but not in Python 3.5.

I'm working in py_file.py ===> H:/other/apple/work_here/py_file.py

I want to import total_text.py from ===> H:/other/apple/banana/total_text.py

The import works in Python 2.7 but not in Python 3.5.  In 3.5 I get a red squiggly line under banana and when I run the code the error reads "No module named 'banana'"

```
import sys
import os
os.chdir(os.path.join("H:\\", "other", "apple", "work_here"))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.split(__file__)[0], ".."))
import banana.total_text
```

To troubleshoot the problem, I executed the following print statements in both programs and found I am getting mixed slashes in Python 3.5 program.

**In Python 2.7, I get:**

print sys.path[0]  =====> H:\other\apple\work_here..  # Note there is a \ after the e in here that did not show up.

print os.listdir(sys.path[0]) =====> [u'banana', u'work_here']

**In Python 3.5 I get the following:**

print sys.path[0]  =====> H:/other/work_here.. # Note there is a \ after the e in here that did not show up.

print os.listdir(sys.path[0]) =====> ['apple', 'work_here']

I searched around and found a partial fix:  By adding os.path.abspath(x) or os.path.normpath(x) where x = os.path.join(os.path.split(**file**)[0], "..") I got it to go back two directories to H:\other ===> The import statement works if I write it like: **import apple.banana.total_text**

**Using the os.path.abspath() version, I get:**

print(sys.path[0])  =====> H:\other

print(os.listdir(sys.path[0])) =====> ['apple', 'work_here']

I am trying to get the Python 3.5 version to work the same way as the Python 2.7 version and understand if what would cause 3.5 to behave differently.

Comment: check os.sep
https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

Comment: I was able to get the 3.5 version to work.  I replaced: sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.split(__file__)[0], "..")) with sys.path.insert(0, '..')

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the 3.5 version to work. I replaced: sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.split(file)[0], "..")) with sys.path.insert(0, '..')

Comment: also, you can leave all that nonsense behind if you put __init__.py in each of your source folders and run from the project directory. Then imports just work.
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: This didn't seem like a popular subject, maybe for the reason you just said.